# Clojure: Idiomatic way to call contains? on a lazy sequence

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

Is there an idiomatic way of determining if a LazySeq contains an element? As of Clojure 1.5 calling `contains?` throws an IllegalArgumentException:

```
IllegalArgumentException contains? not supported on type: clojure.lang.LazySeq      
clojure.lang.RT.contains (RT.java:724)
```

Before 1.5, as far as I know, it always returned false.

I know that calling `contains?` on a LazySeq may never return as it can be infinite. But what if I know it isn't and don't care if it is evaluated eagerly?

What I came up with is:

```
(defn lazy-contains? [col key]
  (not (empty? (filter #(= key %) col))))
```

But it doesn't feel quite right. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, lazy seqs are not efficient for checking membership. Consider using a set instead of a lazy seq.

If a set is impractical, your solution isn't bad. A couple of possible improvements:

1. "Not empty" is a bit awkward. Just using seq is enough to get a nil-or-truthy value that your users can use in an if.You can wrap that in boolean if you want true or false.
2. Since you only care about the first match, you can use some instead of filter and seq.
3. A convenient way to write an equality predicate is with a literal set, like #{key}, though if key is nil this will always return nil whether nil is found our not.

All together that gives you:

```
(defn lazy-contains? [col key]
  (some #{key} col))
```

Comment: The case of having nil as a key makes it somewhat incorrect. But since in my case the key is never nil I can live with it.

Comment: Right. To fix that, just use your original predicate: (some #(= key %) col)

Comment: @Chouser I've been trying to implement any of these alternatives to a specific use and have been running into the following issue. How would I get this to more closely match the original contains? functionality?

(lazy-contains? {:state "active", :course_n "law", :course_i "C0"} :state) returns nil

but when using contains? it returns true

I'm trying to grok through clojuredocs as well and am not seeing how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `some` instead of `filter` as in your example, you'll get an immediate return as soon as a value is found instead of forcing evaluation of the entire sequence.

```
(defn lazy-contains? [coll key]
  (boolean (some #(= % key) coll)))
```

**Edit**: If you don't coerce the result to a boolean, note that you'll get `nil` instead of `false` if the key isn't found.

Comment: Using filter as I did does not evaluate the entire sequence as long as the value is found first.  `(lazy-contains? (range) 100)` returns true. So isn't it equivalent to your function?