# Trying to get a lazy-contains? function in Clojure to return results consistant with contains? when dealing with a map

Tags: clojure, maps, contains, lazy-evaluation

Here's a use of the standard 'contains?' function in Clojure-

```
(contains? {:state "active", :course_n "law", :course_i "C0"} :state)
```

and it returns the expected

```
true
```

I used the following

[Clojure: Idiomatic way to call contains? on a lazy sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264813/clojure-idiomatic-way-to-call-contains-on-a-lazy-sequence)

as a guide for building a lazy-contains? as this is what I need for my present use-case.

The problem I'm facing is that for a map these alternatives are not returning the same answer, giving either a false or a nil response. I've tried looking at the source for contains? and it's slow going trying to understand what's happening so I can correct the lazy-contains? appropriately (for the record Clojure is essentially my first programming language, and my exposure to Java is very limited).

Any thoughts or ideas on how I might approach this? I tried every variant on the linked question I could.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's different about your question that's not covered by Chouser's answer to the question you linked? The answer there sounds like a great answer to your question; if you want some other answer please edit this question to be clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure: Idiomatic way to call contains? on a lazy sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264813/clojure-idiomatic-way-to-call-contains-on-a-lazy-sequence)

Comment: @Thumbnail That name is taken, `(:added (meta #'some?)) ;=> "1.6"`, but it is the complement of `nil?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to remove the error pointed out by @amalloy.

---

I think your problem is with the way that maps present themselves as sequences.

Given

```
(def data {:state "active", :course_n "law", :course_i "C0"})
```

then

```
(seq data)
;([:state "active"] [:course_i "C0"] [:course_n "law"])
```

... a sequence of key-value *pairs*.

So if we define (following [@chouser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16265388/1562315))

```
(defn lazy-contains? [coll x]
  (some #(= x %) coll))
```

... then

```
(lazy-contains? data :state)
;nil
```

... a false result, whereas ...

```
(lazy-contains? data [:state "active"])
;true
```

This is what [@Ankur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24857800/1562315) was getting at, showing you a function treating a map as a sequence consistent with `contains?` on the map itself.

- The standard `contains?` works with *keyed*/*indexed* collections - maps 
  or sets or vectors - where it tests for the presence of a *key*.
- Our `lazy-contains?` works with anything *sequable*, including all the
  standard collections, testing for the presence of a *value*.

Given the way that keyed/indexed collections present as sequences, these are bound to be inconsistent.

Comment: I don't think there was ever a time that `contains?` worked on sequences. I've dug through the git logs too, and can't find any evidence of such a time; are you sure what you're saying is true? If so, can you provide a git SHA which includes this behavior?

Comment: @amalloy Thank you. I misread the question [Clojure: Idiomatic way to call contains? on a lazy sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264813/clojure-idiomatic-way-to-call-contains-on-a-lazy-sequence).

Comment: @amalloy Sorry to have caused you needless work by carelessly jumping to an erroneous conclusion. I'll be more careful in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below implementation (for maps only):

```
(defn lazy-contains? [col key]
  (some (fn [[k v]] (= k key)) col))
```

Remember, `contains?` is to check the existence of a key in a collection, in maps the key is obvious, in other supported collections (like vector) the key is the index.

Comment: Updated: Used the word 'supported collections'

Answer (score 1):

A "lazy" implementation of `contains?` is undesirable where checking for presence

- of a key in a hash-map or of a value in a set

  ```
  (contains? #{:foo} :foo}) => true
  (contains? {:foo :bar} :foo) => true
  ```
- of an index of a vector array or string.

  ```
  (contains? [:foo] 0) => true
  (contains? (int-array 7) 6) => true
  (contains? "foo" 2) => true
  ```

Quoting from the `contains?` docstring:

> **'contains?' operates constant or logarithmic time;   it will not
>   perform a linear search for a value.**

`some` is a tool for linear searching. When searching for an element in a set or vector, it can take the input sequence length times as long as `contains?` or longer in the worst case and will take more time than `contains?` in almost every case.

**`contains?` can't be implemented "lazy"** as it does not produce a sequence. However, `some` stops consuming a lazy sequence as soon as it has determined a return value.

```
(some zero? (range))
;; true
```

Notice that maps and sets are never sequential or lazy.